# “Quelles que soient” or “Quelle que soit”

Tags: grammaire, accord, conjonctions

> Il s'agit de la tendance d'une personne à s'ouvrir aux expériences,
>   quelle que soit la nature de celles-ci.

versus

> Il s'agit de la tendance d'une personne à s'ouvrir aux expériences,
>   quelles que soient la nature de celles-ci.

Opinions ? I'm inclined to use the second one, but wikipedia is stating otherwise.

Comment: Pretty sure “la nature de celles-ci” is extreeeeemely awkward phrasing, but maybe a native speaker will correct me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one is the good one. "Quelle" refers to "nature" which is singular, so no "s".

Answer (score 0):

Vous pouvez éviter l'emploi du subjonctif en disant

> Il s'agit de/C'est la tendance d'une personne à s'ouvrir à des
>   expériences, indépendamment de la nature de celles-ci.

Avec le subjonctif :

> Il s'agit de/C'est la tendance d'une personne à s'ouvrir aux
>   expériences, quelle que soit la nature de celles-ci.

Quelles que soit car l'accord se fait avec la nature (féminin ; singulier).

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quel_que_soit

Attention à la différence quelque vs quel que :

https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-26971.php

Answer (score -2):

`Les deux se dise` et `les deux se disent`.

Ici toutefois, il me semble que le sujet de soit/soient est nature. Qui est au singulier.

Donc:

> Il s'agit de la tendance d'une personne à s'ouvrir aux expériences,
>   quelle que soit la nature de celles-ci.

Et pourtant:

> Il s'agit de la tendance d'une personne à s'ouvrir aux expériences,
>   quelles que soient celles-ci.